# Pycharm: Unresolved attribute reference for class 'SQLAlchemy'

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

Estoy haciendo un tutorial para crear una pagina web usando `Flask` en `Python`.
Estoy usando *PyCharm 2021.1.2 (Community Edition) Build #PC-211.7442.45, built on June 1, 2021*
A la hora de crear la base de datos con `SQLAlchemy` me tira errores diciendo esto:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'Column' for class 'SQLAlchemy'    
Unresolved attribute reference 'Integer' for class 'SQLAlchemy'    
Unresolved attribute reference 'String' for class 'SQLAlchemy'
```

`Column`, `Integer` y `String` me los remarca diciendo precisamente que no los reconoce.
Si me deja compilar pero a la hora de querer crear la base de datos con

```
from market.py import db
db.create_all()
```

No crea absolutamente nada.

Este es mi código para el `market.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQL_ALCHEMY_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Item(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)

    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)

    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)

    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
     items = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'Phone', 'barcode': '893212299897', 'price': 500},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Laptop', 'barcode': '123985473165', 'price': 900},
        {'id': 3, 'name': 'Keyboard', 'barcode': '231985128446', 'price': 150}
     ]
   return render_template('market.html', items=items)
```

Ya probé con Invalidate Caches, con hacer downgrade a la version de SQLAlchemy, ir a la pag oficial y copiar el codigo exacto para crear bases de datos, probé con agregar esto:

```
from sqlalchemy import column, integer, string, float
```

Y ni siquiera lo toma. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: por lo que se existen errores al ejecutarlo con *Pycharm*, prueba haciendo `from sqlalchemy import *`